# Assign a tag to custom post type using a query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, mysql

I have a custom post type `courses` with a custom field `level`. I want to run a query (mysql or WP query) that runs through every course (post) and if the level is greater than 3, append a tag called `higher` to it.

How would I go about this please?

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Put code below to your functions.php

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('post','cpt'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}